# Issue comparing values in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this php code meant to compare two values,a variable `$rate` received from a form which can either have values 'applaud' or 'boo' so I want to check if the value is neither of it and kill the page with an error message.I've tried that but ...`localhost can not handle this request`

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<?php 
$rate=$_POST['rate'];
echo $rate;

?>

<?php

if($rate != 'applaud' OR $rate != 'boo')
{

die("Sorry there was a problem var rate was not well stated");
}

else
{
    echo 'yay ,well stated!!!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will apply some useful check to do so:-

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['rate'])){ //check data is coming or not actually

    $rate= $_POST['rate'];
    if($rate != 'applaud' && $rate != 'boo'){ // use && to check for neither of it
        die("Sorry there was a problem var rate was not well stated");
    }else{
        echo 'yay ,well stated!!!';
    }
}else{
   die("POST data missing!");
}
?>
```

Comment: @TItoAmoo as you want to check that `rate` is neither of those two then only show error. so you have to go for `&&` , if both condition will true then only it will show error otherwise it will pass.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `OR` with `&&` and best way to compare two strings in php is `strcmp()`

```
if(strcmp($rate,"applaud")!=0 && strcmp($rate,"boo")!=0)
 {
    die("Sorry there was a problem var rate was not well stated");
 }
```

If two strings are equal then it will return `0`. If you want to learn more about `strcmp()` then you can visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcmp.asp)

Comment: Sorry! can you explain more  what happens?

Comment: localhost cant handle the request

Comment: I don't think that so that it was caused by `strcmp()`. You might have some other mistakes

Comment: It might be. You can check and compare two strings separately for learning purposes first. I have given you the link of tutorials